# sencha touch clarification on cost and license

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm interested in using Sencha Touch for a Web Mobile Site.

I read on Sencha Touch site that they now offer the Commercial Software License for Free.

I read the license agreement but I still do not have a clear understanding of their prices.

In my case, my customer would hire me to build a mobile website, the site will run in the browser using html and so on and will be accessible directly on a URL. The mobile site will e hosted on a shared hosting rented by the customer, so it is not a App for IOS or Android

In this case:

- may I use the Sencha Touch framework for Free?
- is my client or hosting provider obligated to pay a license?
- As for the license all the copyright for sencha touch must be included, may I protect my intellectual property for the coding done using the frame work?
- in case in future the customer require and App for IOS or Android is the license still for Free?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you send them an email ? That'd be probably the best way to find out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software licensing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software licensing.

Answer (score 1):

Check here : http://www.sencha.com/support/